# Create big navigation bars with title in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm new into iOS development and I'd like to know how to create navigation bars like this one:
[image: Zebra's package manager HOME Tab navigation bar]

I've been creating this manually for some time, but have recently discovered there was a way to accomplish this by using Navigation Items and Bars.

I've also tried looking up on the internet on how to do this, but haven't found anything.

Sorry if it is a stupid question and something really easy to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UINavigationController‘s` `UINavigationBar` has the [`prefersLargeTitles`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles) property. Set it to true to enable large title

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Home"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(refreshBtnAction(_:)))
}
@objc func refreshBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Comment: thank you, I created a navigation bar controller.
But now, how do I add the "refresh" button?

Comment: I did what you did, but the button is placed in the middle of the screen, what should I do? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: well, it seems if I use barButtonSystemItem for the button, it is placed correctly, but if I use a custom image, it is placed in the center of the navbar.

https://imgur.com/TK2D7Wd -> is placed correcly

https://imgur.com/Iz6CWTq -> is placed in the center of the navbar

Comment: one last thing, how would I change the button's size?

Comment: @iAlex11 Use `UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .search, target: self, action: #selector(refreshBtnAction(_:)))`

Answer (score 1):

1. In Xcode go to Interface builder, this a tool which display content
   of a storyboard or a xib files.
2. Select a navigation bar
3. In the attributes inspector which is on the left, you will find a property "Prefers Large Titles". Check it.

[image]

Comment: thank you, this also helped me. By the way, do you know how would I change the size of a UIBarButtonItem programatically? Sorry to bother you

Comment: @iAlex11 you should submit a new question